# Creating a queue for the evaluateJavascript function on a WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

I have a hybrid app; some of my Activities use a WebView to display web content. The web app that I show in the WebView has a JS interface that lets me send commands to the web app to navigate different places or do other things.

For example, if I need my web app to navigate to the "user profile" page, I execute a command like:

```
class SomeActivity: AppCompatActivity {
   ...
   webView.evaluateJavascript("navigateTo(\"userprofile\")")
   ...
}
```

Then, I get a response via the JS interface, and the app reacts accordingly.

I introduced a JS queue to improve performance, so the JS commands are executed sequentially. Instead of calling the `evaluateJavascript()` function directly on the WebView, I've created a custom WebView component with this JS queue set as a property.

```
class SomeActivity: AppCompatActivity {
   ...
   webView.jsQueue.queueEvaluateJavascript("navigateTo(\"userprofile\")")
   ...
}
```

Now I would like to add a new behaviour on top of that, which is being able to *pre-process* the commands within the queue. What I mean by pre-processing is that if I ever queue commands of the same "type", like:

```
class SomeActivity: AppCompatActivity {
   ...
   webView.jsQueue.queueEvaluateJavascript("navigateTo(\"userprofile\")")
   webView.jsQueue.queueEvaluateJavascript("navigateTo(\"about-me\")")
   webView.jsQueue.queueEvaluateJavascript("navigateTo(\"user-list\")")
   ...
}
```

What I would like to happen is that the queue is smart enough to ditch those two first "navigate" commands - `"navigateTo(\"userprofile\")"` and `"navigateTo(\"about-me\")"` - because I don't want my WebView to navigate to those two places just to finally navigate to `"navigateTo(\"user-list\")"`.

The implementation of this JS queue looks like this:

```
class JsQueue(
    private val webView: WebView,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope
) {
    
    init {
        scope.launch { 
            for (jsScript in jsChannel) {
                runJs(jsScript)
            }
        }
    }

    private val jsChannel = Channel<String>(BUFFERED)

    fun queueEvaluateJavascript(script: String) {
        runBlocking {
            jsChannel.send(script)
        }
    }

    suspend fun runJs(script: String) = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->
        webView.evaluateJavascript(script) { result ->
            cont.resume(result)
        }
    }
}
```

- How can I pre-process the js commands in the `Channel<String>` so I
  ditch duplicated js commands?
- Also, sometimes my WebView will become invisible, and I want to *pause* the queue when that happens. I wonder if there's any way to programmatically pause a *Channel*?

**Edit #1**

> Also, sometimes my WebView will become invisible, and I want to
> *pause* the queue when that happens. I wonder if there's any way to programmatically pause a *Channel*?

I've tried using [this](https://github.com/yumemi-yhisano/AACSample/blob/116aa8418b4b03214a2127c5a2a406d5ae74b948/app/src/main/java/com/sample/aacsample/ui/base/PausableDispatcher.kt) `PausableDispatcher` implementation, and it seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to implement this behavior in the JavaScript rather than trying to catch the `evaluateJavascript` calls? If you must do it in Kotlin, you could just as easily create `queueJavascript` and `executeQueue` methods that selectively keeps commands given to it in an array and calls all commands via `evaluateJavascript` when you run the `executeQueue` command.

Answer (score 1):

All of the command examples you gave follow a specific pattern: they're all functions. We can use this to our advantage!

First, let's create some terminology.

`navigateTo()` is a function (of course!).
And lets call the `navigateTo` part of the function a `type`.

An example of some `type`s are:

```
console.log() => `console.log`,
gotoUrl(url) => `gotoUrl`.
```

I just made this terminology up. But it will help you understand the logic.

Now, what we need to do is look at the array of commands, understand it's `type`, and check if any other commands have the same type. If they do, they need to be excluded from the queue before the queue is executed.

Easy!

I've written a sample code that you can integrate with your script:

```
// Example array of commands for demonstration.
let commands = [
    'navigateTo("a")',
    'navigateTo("b")',
    'navigateTo("c")',
];


/** A list of non-duplicate types*/
let types = [];
/** A list of non-duplicate commands */
let newCommands = [];

// Reverse the array because the most important commands start from the end of array.
for(let command of commands.reverse()){
    let type = command.slice(0, command.indexOf('('));
    // Determine if type already exists
    let alreadyExists = false;
    for(let commandType of types){
      if(type == commandType){
        alreadyExists = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    if(alreadyExists)
      // Type already exists. Do not add to command list.
      continue;
    
     // This type & command does not exist.
     // Update command & type arrays
     types.push(type);
     newCommands.push(command)
}

// New Commands
console.log("Commands: ", newCommands);
// If you want to keep same queue order without duplicates:
console.log("Commands: ", newCommands.reverse())
```

Let me know if I missed the mark answering this question. Otherwise, cheers to a great queue system!